# Which API should I use to create multiple Python3 interpreter instances?

Tags: python-3.x, python-embedding

I am embedding Python3 interpreter into Cocoa app.
My app needs multiple separated Python execution contexts, so I need to spawn multiple interpreters.

Python3 manual offers at least two ways to spawn execution context.

- `PyInterpreterState_New`
- `Py_NewInterpreter`

What are them and which should I use to create completely separated python context? (like a system process)

Answer (score 2):

Newbie to embedding Python, but looking at the docs, it seems that [Py_NewInterpreter](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#Py_NewInterpreter) is the way to go. [PyInterpreterState_New](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#PyInterpreterState_New) simply creates a new interpreter state object, while [Py_NewInterpreter](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#Py_NewInterpreter) creates a new sub-interpreter. A sub-interpreter mostly behaves the same as a seperate process, except with some [caveats](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#bugs-and-caveats).

Comment: Yes, and internally `Py_NewInterpreter` calls `PyInterpreterState_New` as the first item before continuing to associate a new `PyThreadState` with the new interpreter and set up the initial interpreter modules.